# Do products derived from coconut need to be kept cool?

Tags: food-safety, storage-method, coconut

I have something that's a mix of coconut oil and butter gee. How should I store it? It turned brick hard when I put it in the refrigerator. [Here is a picture](http://www.healthyplanetcanada.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/600x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/s/t/st-francis-virgin-coconut-oil-butter-ghee-370g-f0e.jpg). UPDATE: I tried keeping it in the cupboard and it completely separated and liquefied :(

I also have something called coconut manna and am not sure if it should be refrigerated?

Comment: Hi Celeritas, your post ended with a separate question unrelated to the rest. We can only answer one question per page, so if you want that answered, you should write up a new question about it. Also, it would need some explanation to understand what exactly you want answered. It is a beginner question, which is not a problem in itself, but if you want to hear more than "it is self evident" or "this doesn't make sense", you can explain what your knowledge of the situation is, why you think the products are "unrelated", so people can tell you how they are related.

Comment: @rumtscho understood.

Comment: Coconut oil solidifies around 80°F (27°C). It's not surprising that happened in the fridge.

Answer (score 2):

No need of refrigerating. We routinely use various forms of coconut oil for cooking and traditionally even for use as hair oil. Same applies to coconut manna. I'm speaking from experience. If you need more proof, there's [this](http://chocolatecoveredkatie.com/2012/06/30/coconut-butter-and-coconut-oil/) and [this](http://nutiva.com/company/faq/coconut-faq/).